# Retrieve response data from stripe in flutter web view

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-web

I am trying to retrieve a response from stripe checkout payment in flutter webView after the payment is complete. The issue I am currently facing is how to view the response I get as I want the details involving the status of the payment and other details.

Additionally I also want that the checkout page redirects to the previous flutter page(Navigator.pop) rather than going to the success url.

Please let me know if you require any further information from my end.

Please find below code for reference :

stripe_web.dart

```
void redirectToCheckout(BuildContext _, var plan) async {
  final stripe = Stripe(apiKey);
  var result = stripe.redirectToCheckout(CheckoutOptions(
    lineItems: [
      LineItem(price: plan, quantity: 1),
    ],
    clientReferenceId: '1',
    mode: 'payment',
    successUrl:
        'https://localhost:8080/#/success/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}', 
    cancelUrl: 'https://localhost:8080/#/cancel',
  ));
  print(result.id); // this is coming as null. 
}
```

this is being displayed in stripe dashboard for the particular payment

```
{
  "id": "cs_test_a18X92AXdkSpTZi8DGQWLvgnrYbze4QqKXI9nqp9OxznKRVF2ZydBfgByi",
  "object": "checkout.session",
  "livemode": false,
  "payment_intent": "pi_3LMP97CeEjBZ7q3i1sInRldA",
  "status": "complete",
  "after_expiration": null,
  "allow_promotion_codes": null,
  "amount_subtotal": 2500000,
  "amount_total": 2500000,
  "automatic_tax": {
    "enabled": false,
    "status": null
  },
```

Comment: You can't really get information from a WebView like that. I'd suggest either using one of the flutter Stripe libraries for a native implementation instead, but either way, you use your _backend_ server to reconcile payments with Stripe, via webhooks, so that's what you should use. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders

Answer (score 0):

You can find the CheckoutSession ID from the URL's query param, so that before [creating](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page#create-success-page) the success page, your backend can make a API call to [retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve#retrieve_checkout_session) the CheckoutSession to examine its status.